# how to add files of Jquery UI slider to wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

This is nagendra, I am new to the wordpress, Can anyone explain how to add Jquery ui slider to slide for price tag reference link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range code to wordpress? and please clearly tell me about files to include code in wordpress. 
Please let me know anyone knows about query?

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_enqueue_script` in your theme's `functions.php` file to load jquery-ui and jquery, if necessary.

Documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script